# What am I missing with this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am missing something very trivial in this regular expression. would you help me figure it out.

Valid Input: `Tonny & 'One' 1234-5 tea be and Z`

Regex: `/^([a-zA-Z',\s,\d,&,#,-,(,)])*$/;`

As per my current regex expression the input is not valid. Its a valid input as per reqs, wondering what I am missing in regex thats not validating the above input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your dash doesn't match because in a character class you need to put the dash first or last.  Also, you don't need all those commas:

```
/^([-a-zA-Z'\s\d&#()])*$/
```

Comment: The parentheses aren't necessary either.

Comment: He's not trying to match the commas at all I believe.

Comment: @Alex, not trying to match commas. I was using commas just as separators between regex elements

Answer (score 2):

Put the `-` character on very first or very last position within `[...]` >>

`/^([-a-zA-Z\s\d',&#()])*$/`

Comment: You may have forgotten a comma `,`.

Comment: The problem is his valid input does not require commas.

Comment: @AlexW - Maybe... It is not clear what exactly OP wants, if to validate just the particular one string, which would be nuts to use regex for that when (s)he can use just compare operator then... :)

Answer (score 1):

This matches it: `^([\w\d&#\(\) '-])*$`

The commas are extraneous.  The thing that fixed it for me was to move the ampersand to the front.